# VBA code to Open .vbs file as another user

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have searched thoroughly and have yet to find the right answer to this question.  Seems the methods below may be dated?

Here is the situation, I have an Access 2010 form with a button that executes a .vbs file that updates Active Directory user logon hours.  This file has to be run with my administrative account which uses an eToken cert and pin for authentication.  Therefore, I need to a windows user logon interface prompt.  Please provide a VBA code sample to if this is possible.

I've tried the following methods without success:

```
Shell "runas.exe /user:administrator ""scriptname.vbs""", vbNormalFocus
```

and

```
ShellExecute 0, "runas", "c:\folder\scriptname.vbs", Command, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run an executable when you use RunAs
Maybe try prefacing vbs file with "Wscript "